# IOS user registration

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, registration

I want to create a user login system that will eventually handle a lot of users and information linked to the users. I've looked a lot into core data but can someone tell me from experience how I should handle my data? Should I use core data? Also I'm programming in swift.

Comment: Core data only stores information on the device.  Perhaps CloudKit or Firebase would be more appropriate

Comment: @LearningCurve Firebase is the best option.

Comment: @Paulw11  +1 On firebase. Especially for beginners.

Comment: It depends..If your app is standalone i.e. no need for server requests etc, then I'd recommend you look into [Realm](https://realm.io/). In my opinion it is way easier and not quite the learning curve in contrast to core data..But if you would want to have a cloud database, then [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) is the way to go.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to develop a user login using core data?

Answer (score 0):

Singing in/up with an email is important for almost every app that requires a social interaction. In the past, developers often used Parse (backend-provider) as to implement a login system. But, Parse is closing down soon. So, here we have another solution, as someone mentioned, "Firebase". Firebase allows you to quickly create a login system integrated with email, Facebook, Github, Google, you name it. You are also able to store user information such as photos and personal information using Firebase's core feature known as 'Real time database' and "Storage". Here is a quick introduction for you to learn more about Firebase!

Introduction to Firebase Authentication
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8sGY55yxicA

Introduction to Firebase Database
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U5aeM5dvUpA

Login Tutorial by Jared
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8sRUhzgJhcY

There is a learning curve, but let me know if you are stuck, 
read the documentation and "get started guideline"

https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup

If you find this information useful, I would appreciate your thumbs up!

Comment: By the way, if you use Core Data, the user information will only be stored in the user's device. You might want to take a look at information about the user. So, I would recommend you to use Firebase to store everything!